# How can i Post Radio Button List with Dynamic names to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am well and truly stuck.
I have created a huge list of radio buttons  on my razor view. Each row is a different set of radio buttons and I have given them each dynamic names.
I am new to MVC and i did not know how i can pass this radio button list to controller

**this is my editor Template**

```
    @model StudentManagement1.TeacherCourseStudent
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Attendance"
}


<tr>


    <td>
       @Model.Student_Id
    </td>

    <td>
        @Model.Student.Name
    </td>

    <td>
        @Model.Student.Sur_Name
    </td>

    <td>
       @Model.Student.Semester.Semester_Name
    </td>

    <td>
    @Html.RadioButton(@Model.Student_Id.ToString(), "present", true)
    </td>

    <td>
    @Html.RadioButton(@Model.Student_Id.ToString(), "absent")
    </td>

    <td>
    @Html.RadioButton(@Model.Student_Id.ToString(), "leave")
    </td>
```

**this is my Razor view**

```
 @model IEnumerable<StudentManagement1.TeacherCourseStudent>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MarkAttendance";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_TeacherLayout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("MarkAttendance", "Attendance", FormMethod.Post))
{
<table cellspacing = "5">
    <tr>
    @Html.Display("Student Id")
    @Html.Display(Name"")
    @Html.Display("Sur Name")
    @Html.Display("Semester")
   @Html.Display("Present")
   @Html.Display("Absent")
    @Html.Display("Leave")
    </tr>
 <tbody>
        @Html.EditorForModel()
</tbody>

</table>
    <input type="submit" value="Save attendance" />
}
}
```

**here my controller Action Method to which i want to pass values**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MarkAttendance(IEnumerable<string> Student_Id)
    {
        return view();
   }
```

Comment: Your action method expects to receive a collection of values named `Student_ID` but you don't appear to be rendering any controls with `<input type="radio" name="Student_ID" ..>`.

Comment: you must use List ModelBinding  http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/